# Azure function key-value configuration returning null in the cloud but not locally

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, .net-6.0

I am trying to connect to my azure key vault from an azure function and in my configuration in the azure portal I have a MyUri config with my value. **The same both on my app function config and local.settings.json**. I already double-checked that is not a typo.

My Startup.cs code looks something like this:

```
    public override void ConfigureAppConfiguration(IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder builder)
    {
        var vaultUri = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MyUri", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
        var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
        var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
        builder.ConfigurationBuilder
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .AddAzureKeyVault(vaultUri, keyVaultClient, new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager())
            .Build();
    }

    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
     <some_code>...
    }
```

Using my local.setttings.json in my machine works, but when I publish it in the azure portal I get:

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExternalStartupException : Error building configuration in an external startup class. ---> System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'vault') at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault.AzureKeyVaultConfigurationProvider..ctor(IKeyVaultClient client,String vault,IKeyVaultSecretManager manager,Nullable`1 reloadInterval) at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault.AzureKeyVaultConfigurationSource.Build(IConfigurationBuilder builder) at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build() at NSMG_DocuSign.Startup.ConfigureAppConfiguration(IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder builder)
```

I am using .NET 6 and VS 2022.

Answer (score 0):

You did misunderstand the functionality of `local.settings.json`.
The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=windows%2Cportal%2Cv2%2Cbash&pivots=programming-language-csharp#local-settings) states:

> When running in a function app in Azure, settings required by your functions are stored securely in app settings. During local development, these settings are instead added to the Values object in the local.settings.json file. The local.settings.json file also stores settings used by local development tools.

In your case, you need to add the parameter 'vault' to the [app settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings?tabs=portal#settings) of the azure function.

Comment: I do have MyUri setted in my function -> configuration and it is the same key-value as the one in local.settings.json